# How do I base an Outlook rule on the number of “CC:” addresses?

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I need to create a rule that will pop up a warning when there are more than ten email addresses in the "CC:" field.

I found this code for email addresses in the "To:" field.
How do I switch it to look at the CC email addresses rather than To?

```vb
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim Recipients As Integer
    Dim Start As Integer
    Dim Last As Integer
    Recipients = 1
    Do
        Start = Last + 1
        Last = InStr(Start, Item.To, ";")
        If Last = 0 Then Exit Do
        Recipients = Recipients + 1
    Loop
    If (Recipients > 10) Then
        Cancel = (MsgBox(Str(Recipients) & " recipients in To field.", vbOKCancel) = vbCancel)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `item.cc` https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/mailitem-cc-property-outlook

Comment: also, `Recipients = ubound(split(item.cc,";"))` should do the count, so no need for code up to the IF

Answer (score 0):

i am unable to post a "comment", so i am posting an "answer"

the "split" function returns an array, which is zero based (first element is at index 0)

therefore, ubound returns a 9 for a 10 element array

here is the code, with the change suggested by Nathan_Sav,

plus a change in code to add one to the result of the ubound function

also ... the dialog, that pops up when there are too many recipients, does not mention what happens when you press either of the buttons

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim Recipients As Integer

    Recipients = ubound(split(item.cc,";")) + 1   ' shift array index by one

    If (Recipients > 10) Then
        Cancel = (MsgBox(Str(Recipients) & " recipients in CC field.", vbOKCancel) = vbCancel)
    End If

End Sub
```